# Cryptographic hash function to map interval onto itself

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, one-way-function

Is there any existing approach to construct perfect hash function that map `[0, M)` to `[0, M)`? It should be one to one mapping and one-way.

```
f(value, salt) -> hashed_value
```

Comment: It's odd to call it a hash function if it's 1-to-1. You're looking for a one-way permutation.

Comment: @Mikero really. Thanks.

Comment: One one-way permutation is defined [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/one-way-permutations-without-trapdoor#:~:text=https%3A//cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3655/16703). Not sure about the security, but it is number oriented.

Comment: Thank you. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Uh, I guess you could since this was about identifying the function mostly. If the question comes along again we can repeat, as I'm not sure anybody would find this one. And you've got your answer anyway :)

Comment: Are you looking something like [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)?

Comment: Maybe it is me, but I'm not understanding that comment. Where is the sequence? A range is not a sequence by itself and you're not going to shuffle the entire range to build a permutation I would assume.